# Strongly inert subgroup implies inert subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm preparing a seminar about particular groups with finite conjugacy classes, i.e. inertial groups (see definitions below). My main reference is [this article by my professor](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1346.20046). Be aware that these definitions aren't universally accepted, and someone might find a similar concept defined as [Conjugate-commensurable subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate-commensurable_subgroup).

#### Definition 1

> A subgroup $X$ of a group $G$ is said to be *inert* if the index $|X:X\cap X^g|$ is finite for each element $g$ of $G$.

#### Definition 2

> A subgroup $X$ of a group $G$ is called *strongly inert* if the index $|\langle X,X^g \rangle : X|$ is finite for each element $g$ of $G$.

A groups is said to be (*strongly*) *inertial* if every subgroup is (strongly) inert.
The next proposition that I'd like to prove is bypassed in every article I checked, so it should be fairly simple...

#### Proposition 1

> Prove that if a subgroup $X$ is strongly inert, then it's also inert.

An idea could be to use the [Second isomorphism theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Second_isomorphism_theorem) but I don't know if $X$ is normal in $\langle X,X^g \rangle$.
Note that the other implication is false (e.g. infinite dihedral group).

Comment: Where does this question come from? ("Inert" means something different for free groups, about ranks of intersections.)

Comment: From here [On Inert Subgroups of a Group](http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_2006__115__137_0.pdf)

Comment: Well, that doesn't mention "strongly inert"! Do you have a reference for the other definition too?

Comment: Oh yeah, the reference is this one but I don't think I can share the pdf here [Some Topics in the Theory of Groups with Finite Conjugacy Classes](http://www.aracneeditrice.it/index.php/pubblicazione.html?item=9788854881167)

Comment: That's great, I can find the paper (use the full citation as well as the pdf: Catino, F., and F. de Giovanni. "Some topics in the theory of groups with finite conjugacy classes." Algoritmica, 1. *Aracne Editrice, Rome*, 2015. x+107 pp. ISBN: 978-88-548-8116-7. You can also link to its [Zenterblatt review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1346.20046), although the one here ends on quite a weak note!). You should edit these references into the question, along with some sort of commentary, e.g. "I was reading *this* monograph, and it claimed that strongly inert subgroups are inert, without proof" etc.

Comment: I just realised your edit from an hour ago didn't load until after I'd posted that comment. Your edits improve the question, but you should still include the references in the question (comments are designed to be deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove first that, if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of finite index in a group $G$, then so is $H \cap K$.

So, in the problem, if $X$ is strongly inert in $G$, then $X$ and $X^g$ both have finite index in $\langle X,X^g \rangle$, and hence so does $X \cap X^g$.

Comment: I like this one, it really resonates with me haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I write $g=h\pmod{K}$ to mean $gK=hK$, i.e. $g^{-1}h\in K$.

**Lemma.** If $X$ is strongly inert in $G$, then $X$ is inert in $G$.

*Proof.*
Suppose $a, b\in X$ are such that $a=b\pmod {X\cap X^g}$, so $a^{-1}b\in X\cap X^g$, then also $a^{-1}b\in X^g$ so we have $a=b\pmod{X^g}$. As $a, b\in X$, this means that there is an injection from $X/(X\cap X^g)$ to $\langle X, X^g\rangle/X^g$. Therefore, it is sufficient to prove that $\langle X, X^g\rangle/X^g$ is finite, i.e. $|\langle X, X^g\rangle:X^g|<\infty$.

Now, $G$ is strongly inert and so $|\langle X, X^{g^{-1}}\rangle:X|<\infty$. Conjugating by $g$ gives us that $|\langle X, X^{g}\rangle:X^g|<\infty$ QED.